# difference between null string and none

Tags: javascript, css, webkit

I have the following script:

```
document.querySelector(".img-man").style.webkitAnimation = "";
```

Which was working on safari 5.1.7 but not on 7.0.2.

Later I changed to this:

```
document.querySelector(".img-man").style.webkitAnimation = "none";
```

Which is working fine now.

So, I'm curious to know the difference between `"" and "none"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the property to "none" explicitly disables animation.

[Link](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-animation-name)

Answer (score 1):

> *"Then now it's not working in 5.1.7. So, what should I do?"*

The issue with *"none"* not working could perhaps be fixed by using a dummy name:

```
document.querySelector(".img-man").style.webkitAnimation = "dummy";
```

As this is done trough JavaScript an alternative could be:

```
document.querySelector(".img-man").style.removeProperty('-webkit-animation-name');
```

*OK. OP removed this part of the question after I wrote it, but leave it as it might help both him and others.*

---

For the property itself; From Safari documentation we have for [webkit-animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-_webkit_animation) the sub property [-webkit-animation-name](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-_webkit_animation_name):

> **-webkit-animation-name**
>
> *Specifies the name of an animation.*
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> -webkit-animation-name: name [, ...]
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>    *name*
>
> > The name of the animation.
> >
> > The name is used to select the -webkit-keyframe at-rule that provides the keyframes and property values for the animation. If the name does not match any -webkit-keyframe at-rule, there are no properties to be animated and the animation is not executed. See “[@-webkit-keyframes](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/OtherStandardCSS3Features.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007601-SW4)” for a description of this rule.
> >     If *"none"*, no animation is executed even if there is a -webkit-keyframe at-rule with that name. Setting this property to "none" explicitly disables animations.
> >     The default value is "".

---